# Rails: Add an existing child as a new association to parent model via ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, activerecord, parent-child

I try to add an existing child model to the parent via ajax, by only providing the new id.

My models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
  attr_accessible :books
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to: :user
end
```

In my html form the user is viewing a User and it can select an existing Book to add. This will result in an Ajax request. I would like to only send the new Book, and not all the already assigned books. E.g. the User model has already Books 1 and 2, and now to user selects Book 3 to also be assigned.

I can not find the correct structure of the parameters. If I use the following, it completely overwrites the current associations.

```
// Ajax parameters
user[books] = [3]
```

How should is build the parameters such that it only adds the new book? And as a follow-up, how can I build the parameters to remove only a single association?

Answer (score 2):

You have to send only one "book_id" in request.
Then in controller:

```
# assuming params hash is { :book_id => 3 }

@book = Book.find params[:book_id]
@user.books << @book
...

# Removing
@user.books.delete(@book)


# In `update` action

params[:user][:book_ids] = (@user.book_ids + params[:user][:book_ids]).flatten
@user.update_attributes(params[:user])
```

Comment: Thank you cutalion. But do I understand correctly I can not use this in combination with the default "update" method in my controller, and the @user.update_attributes(params[:books]) ?

Comment: You can use `book_ids` there. But then you should set all books. I'll update the answer